# cy.wait() timed out waiting 5000ms for the 1st request to the route when using cypress intercept

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress, cypress-intercept

I'm attempting to mimic Cypress intercept from a youtube tutorial but for some reason mine isn't working.

Here's the code identical to the tutorial

```js
   it.only('test api with simple intercept stubbing', () => {

        cy.visit('https://dummyapi.io/explorer');

        cy.intercept({
            path: 'data/v1/post/60d21af267d0d8992e610b8d/comment?limit=10'
        }).as('comments')

        cy.get('.flex > :nth-child(5)').click();
        cy.wait('@comments').then(intercept => {
            cy.log(JSON.stringify(intercept.response.body));
            expect(intercept.response.body.limit).equal(10)
        })
    })
```

Looking in the cypress debug console I can actually see the comments element that was clicked but it just hangs on the cy.wait

[image]

So it's navigating to the page, clicking 'comments', but then it just hangs on cy.wait and never asserts a successful GET.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the `path` option in `cy.intercept()` RouteMatcher object it needs to have a leading path separator `/`.

```js
cy.intercept({
    path: '/data/v1/post/60d21af267d0d8992e610b8d/comment?limit=10'
}).as('comments')
```

[image]